# ASP.NET multiline textbox issue with javascript and AJAX (Jquery)

Tags: asp.net

In my web application I have a textbox called "Address" which is multiline and have 3 rows and 250 characters.

I am calling a javascript function in which i am calling AJAX to send the data to a webservice for some processing but AJAX is unable to process variable which contains multiline text.

I am reading multiline textbox value like this in javascript function.

```
var puid = document.getElementById('<%=userid.ClientID%>').value;
var paddress = document.getElementById('<%=xaddress.ClientID%>').value;
```

and passing like this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : "DataService.asmx/UpdateProfile",
    data: "{'puserid': ' " + puid +   'padd': ' " + paddress +  " '}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    error: OnError
});
```

If I comment paddress parameters in ajax "data:" it works fine other wise ajax goes on "OnError" ...Oh i just figured out that my address has **'B' Area** (apostrophe) in it thats why it its giving this problem. So how to parse apostrophe as textbox value and read in javascript variable and write back in database similary.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the [jQuery Post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function instead. Your GET request URIs shouldn't have new line chars in them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var puid = document.getElementById('<%=userid.ClientID%>').value;
var paddress = document.getElementById('<%=xaddress.ClientID%>').value;

puid  => string value 
paddress => string value 

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url : "DataService.asmx/UpdateProfile",
  data: {'puserid': puid  , 'padd': paddress },  need = >"," 
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: OnSuccess,
  error: OnError
});
```

Comment: Oh i solved my problem by writing var newadd = paddress.replace(/'/g, "\\'"); :)